# Use of the word 'direction' / 'in direction of'

Tags: prepositions

For the picture added, which of the following fits best:

a. He is facing the direction of the hill.

b. His face is towards the direction of the hill.

c. He is facing the hill.

d. His face is towards hill.

[image]

If we see these in Oxford dictionary:

1. The terrace faces south.
2. Most of the rooms face the sea.
3. Which direction are you facing?*

I think C & D are correct.

Comment: Option C is definitely the most fit one here. Option D sounds okay too.

Comment: a) and b) are much too cumbersome. You could also say 'He is facing towards the hill'.